# How to fetch TestPlan from TFS 2018 U2 via REST API

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I tried to fetch the `TestPlan` results using the below URL
:

URL: `https://{host}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/testplan/plans?api-version=4.1`

I also tried with other API Versions: **5.0-preview.1**, **5.1-preview.1**

I'm getting an `HTTP: 404 Not found` Error. so my question here, is Microsoft Supports Rest API for fetching `TestPlan` for TFS 2018 U2 or if SOAP API is available, please suggest me how to fetch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the old api to get a test plan:

```
 ITestManagementTeamProject proj = GetProject(serverurl, project);
 ITestPlan plan= proj.TestPlans.Find(xx);
```

Comment: Thanks @CeceDong, I think it will solve my issue and i also got SOAP API to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the REST methods to fetch test plans and tests are not available for TFS 2018 U2. You can check that on the documentation page.

For v 5.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0:

[image]

For v TFS 2018 U2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1:

[image]